# jq: reduce json arrays with a Math function

Tags: json, jq

I wrote this JSONProcessor bash function to sum, average, get min and get max values from arrays based on the name values. The average and min results are not correct and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
function JSONProccessor {
 jq '
  def myMathFunc:
    if (.name | test("^sum", "")) then
      {"\(.name)": (.values | add)}                           
    elif (.name | test("^avg|^global-avg", "")) then
      {"\(.name)": ((.values | add) / (.values | length)) }   
    elif (.name | test("^max", "")) then
      {"\(.name)": (.values | max) }   
    elif (.name | test("^min", "")) then
      {"\(.name)": (.values | min) } 
    else
      {"\(.name)": .values[]}                              
    end;

   [
  .Response.stats.data[] |
  .identifier.names[] as $name |
  .identifier.values[] as $val |
  {"\($name)": "\($val)"} + ([
    .metric[] | myMathFunc
  ] | add)
]
'  < ${1} > ${2}
}
```

Input JSON

```
{
  "Response" : {
    "TimeUnit" : [ 1588153140000, 1588153200000 ],
    "metaData" : {
      "errors" : [ ]
    },
    "resultTruncated" : false,
    "stats" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy" ],
          "values" : [ "authn" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "prod",
          "name" : "min(request_processing_latency)",
          "values" : [ 917.0, 6.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "prod",
          "name" : "avg(total_response_time)",
          "values" : [ 2203.5, 13.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "prod",
          "name" : "max(request_processing_latency)",
          "values" : [ 1286.0, 6.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "prod",
          "name" : "global-avg-total_response_time",
          "values" : [ 1473.3333333333333 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "prod",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 2.0, 1.0 ]

        } 
        ]
      }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "apiproxy": "authn",
    "min(request_processing_latency)": 923,
    "avg(total_response_time)": 2216.5,
    "max(request_processing_latency)": 1292,
    "global-avg-total_response_time": 1473.3333333333333,
    "sum(message_count)": 3
  }
]
```

Can you please review and let me know if I am missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, but the `test()` function does not "need" the 2nd argument `""` as you have defined. You just need the `test()` function to return a bool to assert your match. Removing the 2nd argument should make your function work as expected.

The `test()` function supports prototypes `test(REGEX; FLAGS)` where [FLAGS](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) defined in don't matter your logic at all. The `test()` function does not even take arguments separated by `,` but only by `;` de-limiter.

[jq-play snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/hFm_fJuNJ7)